# infile won't open in c++ on mac

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks

Hello I am following a tutorial on youtube that is beginning with in files and out files.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
infile.open("numbers.rtf");

//Check for Error
if (infile.fail())
{
   cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
   exit(1);
}

int x, y;

infile >> x >> y;
cout << "num 1 =" << x << endl;
cout << "num 2 =" << y << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am running on a mac so the .txt file is .rtf. Even after changing that extension the error message still comes up. Heading to school now, appreciate responses

Comment: You are probably making a bad assumption about the working directory - either make sure the working directory is correct or use a full path for your input file.

Comment: Besides, reading an rtf like that will show up extraneous formatting information, use a plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Has nothing to do with the type of file you are opening.
In case you are compiling from command line, place the file `number.rtf` in the same folder from which you're launching your executable, and it should find the file.

Otherwise, use a full pathname for the `.rtf` file.

PS: You can use a `.txt` file extension on a mac as well. `.rtf` is just the default.

Comment: It's not true that the working directory will be the same as the source directory - it *may* be the case when compiling from the command line, but in general it is not.

Comment: I edited it for you. But - instead of just acknowledging what @PaulR said, you should have taken his advice and changed the answer (using the 'edit' link).